# How to fix strange dart error on http call

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting the following error at run time I am doing an http call and getting json back.

"_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type '() => void')"

### Here is my code

```
   class _ForumPostsState extends State<ForumPosts> {
List data;
String categoryID = 'D64D0737-746D-4562-8C10-6445F4069A92';
Future<String> getPostsByCategory() async {
    var response = await http.post(
 Uri.encodeFull("http://api/ForumPostsByCategory"),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
      body: json.encode({'categoryID' : categoryID }));  
     this.setState(
         data = json.decode(response.body)

     );
    print(data[1]["title"]);

return "Success!";
}
```

The error is thrown on this line

```
data = json.decode(response.body)
```

While debugging I noticed that the JSON was there it just errors on the data = json.decode call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
this.setState(
     data = json.decode(response.body)

  );
```

To this:

```
 this.setState(() {
     data = json.decode(response.body)
    }
 );
```

More info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: im not sure what the difference is but thank u worked perfectly